# Mockito and EJB

Tags: ejb, testng, mockito

Good evening everybody,
I have a EJB class. This class has 2  attributes are EJB, with private access, and "injected" with EJB annotation @EJB. This class has no defined constructor.
I want to test this class by using Mockito.
I have 2 problems :
1) the 2 attributes are with private access 
2) Even when i want to put a defined constructor with the 2 EJB attributes as parameters, it does not work in my TestNG class 
In my TestNG class, 
i only want instantiate my class of course, 
and also her 2 EJB attributes as 2 mocks. 
And i do not succeed. 
Thank you very much, 
  Thomas

This is the class.

```
package fr.nomenclature.service;

@Stateless
@Local
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)
public class TraitementNomenclaturesImpl implements TraitementNomenclatures {

     private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TarificationFactureImpl.class);

    @EJB(name = "AccesNomenclatures-interne-ebx") 
    private transient AccesNomenclatureEBX accesEbx;

    @EJB(name = "AccesElementFacturation-interne-ebx")
    private transient AccesElementFacturationEBX accesRefEbx;

        /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see
     * fr.atom.referentiel.sante.nomenclature.service.TraitementNomenclature#extraireNomenclaturesDesPrestations(java
     * .util.List, java.util.Date, fr.atom.configuration.SoapContext)
     */
    @Override
    public ContenusNomenclatures extraireNomenclaturesDesPrestations(
            final List<PrestationDeSante<? extends Identifiant>> pPrestations, final Date pDateTraitement,
            final SoapContext pContext) {

                    .......

    }
}
```

Comment: You can use the `@InjectMocks` annotation for this.  Check the docs.

Comment: Thank you David. <br/> In fact it works. <br/> In the class TraitementNomenclaturesImpl, I just create a constructor with my 2 EJB attributes, and in my testNG classes, i create, "instantiate" these 2 attributes as Mock (attribut = mock(AccesNomenclatureEBX.class) and after, create, "instantiate" an object of type TraitementNomenclaturesImpl, with his constructor taking in arguments the 2 mocks newly created. <br> Thank you David.